# set value to list inside another list

Tags: c#, list, object, syntax

MyItems model class contains list of MyItemGallery items. I am able to loop though each MyItems to add value but problem is i dont know how can i add value to MyItemGallery which is inside MyItems? Can you provide an example so i can understand how can i set value to MyItemGallery?

Controller:

```
List<MyItems> MyItemList = new List<MyItems>();

Items //Items contains list of some items data
foreach (var Item in Items)
{
    MyItemList.Add(new MyItems {
        EbayID = 1,
        Title = "some title",
        UserStoresID = 20
    });
}
```

MyItems.cs:

```
namespace Test_Console
{
    class MyItems
    {

        public string EbayID { get; set; }

        public string Title { get; set; }

        public int UserStoresID { get; set; }

        public List<MyItemGallery> MyItemGallery { get; set; }
    }

    class MyItemGallery
    {
        public int ItemID { get; set; }
        public string GalleryURL { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Comment: `new MyItems { MyItemGallery = new List<MyItemGaller> { whatEverGallery } }`? However we can´t know where that galery comes from. Anyway you should consider to give your class the name of a *single* item, which is `MyItem`, but `MyItems`. This makes is clearer what an instance of this class actually is.

Comment: foreach (var Item in Items) here in item there gallery data also available inside each item list. Meaning each item contains a list of gallery item

Comment: Then what´s your problem? `new MyItem { Gallery = item.Gallery }`

Comment: But can u answer me how can i implement this with foreach loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not 100% clear what exactly you really want to achieve, but taking your question literally, you can easily add a single item to the Gallery when creating your main item, using the same object-creation pattern you've already employed to create and populate your instance of `MyItem`:

```
List<MyItems> MyItemList = new List<MyItems>();

Items //Items contains list of some items data
foreach (var Item in Items)
{
    MyItemList.Add(new MyItems {
        EbayID = 1,
        Title = "some title",
        UserStoresID = 20,
        MyItemGallery = new List<MyItemGallery>() { 
         new MyItemGallery() { ItemId = 1, GalleryURL = "http://www.example.com/gallery" } 
       }
    });
}
```